# Using GDS to make a neo4j undirected graph

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, undirected-graph

The neo4j Graph Data Science (GDS) "Triangle Count" algorithm only runs on an undirected graph. I can convert my existing directed graph to undirected for the calculation using:

CALL gds.graph.create('myGraph3', '*', {BELONGS_TO: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}, FLOWS_TO: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}})

But I have to list every relationship, which is brittle and lengthy for the actual list of relationships.  Is there a way to make the '*' work with this?

Something like

CALL gds.graph.create('myGraph3', '*', {'*': {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED'}})

which does not work, but I can't figure the correct pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible, there is a type parameter where you can input the wildcard option:

```
CALL gds.graph.create('myGraph3', 
   '*', 
   {ALL: {orientation: 'UNDIRECTED', type:'*'}})
```

Comment: Thank you!  It runs at least.  Is there a way to display the named graph in neo4j or networkx so that I can see if it appears as it should?  I cannot figure out how after trying all day.  Neo4j wants to display the database or a MATCH query, not the named graph.  Networkx the same, as near as my skills could find.  How do I determine if I got it "right"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ephemeral graph from the projection.  This ephemeral graph is an in-memory version that can be queried with Cypher so that you can see if it is correct or not.

CALL gds.ephemeral.database.create(
'ephemeralDatabaseName', 'existingProjectedGraph'
)
YIELD
dbName,    graphName,  createMillis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).